# How to add objects from json data to nsmutable array?

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I want to add array object from json data, now I can show my array elements on uitableview header but I want to show with json data. I never worked using json so please help me.

Adding my json and codes below...

[MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6GZR.png)[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol9Gj.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[self.arrHeader addObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"Data"]];` after check that if array count > 0 than tableview reload

Comment: Don't post images. Post text.

Comment: -(void) retriveData{
@try{
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:LIST_URL];
NSString *subCategory=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"sub_category_id"];
NSDictionary *params=@{@"sub_cat_id":_strCategory};
IEURLConnection *connection=[IEURLConnection connectionKolapuriWithParams:params andMethod:@"" withURL:strURL delegate:self];
connection.didFailWithErrorHandler=^(NSError *error){
NSLog(@"ERROR %@",error.localizedDescription);
};

Comment: connection.didFinishLoadingHandler=^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData){
@try{
NSDictionary *responseObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if([_arrHeader count]>0){
[_arrHeader removeAllObjects];
_arrHeader=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
BOOL bResult=[[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"] boolValue];
if (bResult){
NSArray *categoryInfo=[responseObject objectForKey:@"Data"];
for (int i=0; i<[categoryInfo count]; i++){
ShoeTypeObject *shoe=[[ShoeTypeObject alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

Do this where Your response is Coming

```
 //Sucess Response
 self.arrHeader=[ResponseObject valueForKey:@"Data" ];
_tblCatgori.delegate=self;
_tblCatgori.dataSource=self;
[_tblCatgori reloadData];
```

Comment: I thing my code is wrong so I can't catch the response

Comment: @anupam Das please send your API i ll make response for u

Comment: actually I want to display @"category_name" into tableview header